# Failed to decrypt data: Error 0x00000000: Failure on CryptUnprotectData() Delete corrupt

Tags: flutter

Failed to decrypt data: Error 0x00000000: Failure on CryptUnprotectData() Delete corrupt file: c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\com.example\easy_sell\flutter_secure_storage.dat

after upgrade pubspeck.yaml i have this error.

Comment: Provide with a minimal reproducible code example to reproduce the error. The way the question is asked presently is insufficient to understand & resolve

Comment: @Prashant https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues/603#issuecomment-1769261086